# Modify grep results to print a particular word from a match string

Tags: shell, grep

I have a grep ouput which looks as follows:

```
Path to log files = /data/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00001/LOGSTREAM0000/
Database is in write suspend state = YES
Path to log files = /data/db2inst1/NODE0001/SQL00001/LOGSTREAM0001/
Database is in write suspend state = NO
```

I want to edit this as follows:

```
Node = NODE0000
Database is in write suspend state = YES
Node = NODE0001
Database is in write suspend state = NO
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Show your `grep` command. Adding another pipeline to the output of `grep` is really bad choice

Comment: grep -e "Database is in write suspend state" -e "Path to log files" /tmp/dbcfg1.out

Comment: @Inian There's nothing wrong with piping grep into another command.

Comment: @melpomene: I never said anything wrong. I just claimed it can be done in a single command over using two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to keep pipelines of `grep` to generate the output you are looking for. `Awk` is a bit powerful than `grep` in a way it allows you to do transformation on the text that you've matched, which is quite powerful. So with that, all you need for your example would be

```
awk '/Path to log files/{match($0,/NODE([^/]+)/,a); printf "Node = NODE%s\n",a[1];next}
    /Database is in write suspend state/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$  awk -F"/" '{if(NR!=1) if($1 ~ /Path to log files/) print $1,$4 ;else print ;else print "Node = "$4 }' temp
Node = NODE0000
Database is in write suspend state = YES
Path to log files =  NODE0001
Database is in write suspend state = NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed (that can also replace your `grep` command):

```
sed -n '/^Database is in write suspend state/p;
        /^Path to log files = /s|.*/.*\(NODE[0-9]\+\).*/$|Node = \1|p' file
```